# Open Google Incognito using AHK without a non-Incognito window

Tags: incognito-mode

If I open Incognito without opening first a non-Incognito I can't search in Incognito...

```
F::run, C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --incognito
```

(I use "F" just for faster in testing.)

To be able to search in incognito, I have to open first a non-incognito window.

Is it possible to open Google Incognito using AHK without opening first a non-incognito window?

Answer (score 0):

if you use a layer beetween for e.g. VNC connection you could use imageSearch. You could see a working example here on youtube: https://youtu.be/sPdgCjLFc54
BTW VNC server and VNC client at the same machine with same IP.
helps that?